# How to achieve 3 days moving average in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble with a task in SQL Server. The name of the table I'm aiming to create is called 'target'.

```
CREATE TABLE target 
(
    [entry_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [value] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL,
)

INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-01', 10, 1);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-02', 20, 2);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-03', 10, 3);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-04', 30, 4);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-05', 10, 3);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-06', 11, 3);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-06', 40, 6);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-07', 10, 2);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-08', 50, 5);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-09', 10, 8);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-10', 60, 9);
INSERT target VALUES ( '2012-02-10', 50, 9);
```

Based on above data, I want get output like below:

```
entry_date |value|id  |averagevaluesof_3days
-----------+-----+----+----------------------
2012-02-01 |10   |1   |  10
2012-02-02 |20   |2   |  10
2012-02-03 |10   |3   |  13.3
2012-02-04 |30   |4   |  20
2012-02-05 |10   |3   |  16.6
2012-02-06 |40   |6   |  30.3
2012-02-06 |11   |3   |  30.3
2012-02-07 |10   |2   |  23.6
2012-02-08 |50   |5   |  37
2012-02-09 |10   |8   |  23.3
2012-02-10 |60   |9   |  56.6
2012-02-10 |50   |9   |  56.6
```

I need to calculate the average values of the running last three days of information at date (`entry_date`).

Let me provide an example further explaining my goal:

**Entry_date**: `2012-02-01`

This date have value and back 2 days don't have value then 2012-02-01 average value is 10 if we take 2012-02-02 date have value and back 2 days means 2012-02-01 and 2012-01-31 here we have  2012-02-01 date value but we don't have 2012-01-31 date value then take  3 days average for  2012-02-02 date is 10 ((10+20)/3 =10) if we take 2012-02-03  is 13.3  ((10+20+10)/3 = 13.3)

Please tell me how to write a query to achieve this task for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    [entry_date], [value], [id], Totol_3daysValue / DaysCount AS Avg_3days
FROM 
    target t
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT 
         SUM(tt.Value) Totol_3daysValue, 
         CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(tt.value) > 1 
               THEN 3.0 
            ELSE 1.0 
         END AS DaysCount
     FROM 
         target tt
     WHERE 
         tt.entry_date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -2, t.entry_date) AND t.entry_date) av
```